# What's the usage of longSwipes and shortSwipes config in swiper？

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

When I read the swiper's docs,  I can not get  what's the usage of longSwipes. Can anyone tell me ? It's best to give an example. Thanks.
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#swiper-full-html-layout

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Old post but here are my findings...

By default `shortSwipes` moves to the next slide with a very short swipe distance. Long swipe moves to the next slide when the current slide is dragged > 50% of the view.

When setting `shortSwipes` to `false`, you now have to drag the slide more than 50% of the view to advance to the next/prev slide.

When setting `longSwipes` to `false`, you now can only advance to the next/prev slide with a very short drag.

When setting both `shortSwipes` and `longSwipes` to `false`, swiping becomes disabled.